How to calculate worked hours - Day, Evening and Night shift - with midnight crossing
I have a schedule template with a shift start time and end time, and I'm trying to calculate hours worked in the Day (6am-4:00pm), Evening (4pm-8pm) and Night (8pm-5:30am). I'm convinced that there has to be a better way than using IF combined with <> and also I'm trying to figure out a workaround for the times crossing midnight. Also to be noted, my tests are regular formulas but only for trial, the end formula would need to be an arrayformula.
For example; Start Time: 9:00 AM / End Time: 9:00 PM = 7h for day, 4h for evening, 1h for night.

My trial formulas can be found in columns BA on onwards, any input would be appreciated.
Here is a link to the sheet

In the linked sheet there are hardly any formulas, the same data is contained multiple times, it seems that your main goal was to follow a formatted template. Is this used as input like a form as well?

I have adjusted my example to match the times noted in the description. ie. the description said "Day" and the example said "Morning". They now match.

@cyberbrain the trial formulas start in column AW for example in AX5 it is:=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MOD(
IF(AO5:AO>AP5:AP,
Ref_Config!$G$8-
IF((TIMEVALUE(AO5:AO)>=TIMEVALUE(Ref_Config!$G$7))(TIMEVALUE(AO5:AO)<=TIMEVALUE(Ref_Config!$G$8)),AO5:AO,"x")
,
IF((TIMEVALUE(AP5:AP)<=TIMEVALUE(Ref_Config!$G$8)),AP5:AP,Ref_Config!$G$8)-
IF((TIMEVALUE(AO5:AO)>=TIMEVALUE(Ref_Config!$G$7))(TIMEVALUE(AO5:AO)<=TIMEVALUE(Ref_Config!$G$8)),AO5:AO,"x")
),1)*24))

@cyberbrain the times in the schedule section is just for sample data to use with the formulas further to the right that are for calculating Day/Evening/Night

since this is a fairly easy calculation, the only room for error can happen within the logic itself, therefore, for ease of understanding, this answer will demonstrate a solution based on predefined standards (not as they are presented in the question):

start time and end time are valid timevalues formatted as 24-hour clock
timevalues are converted for calculation to seconds - smallest meaningful unit of time - to avoid decimals and timevalue conversion errors

following formula calculates how many decimal hours were forked per day, calculated from the start/end time, where DAY is defined as the time period starting from 6:00 and ending at 16:00:
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(LET(b, B2:B20, c, C2:C20, 
 bb, b*86400, cc, c*86400, cd, cc+((c<b)*86400), 
 IF((bb>57600)*(cd>cc)*(cc>21600), 
   MAP(cc, LAMBDA(cc, MIN(cc-21600, 36000))), 
   MAP(BYROW(cd, LAMBDA(cd, MIN(cd, 57600))), 
       BYROW(bb, LAMBDA(bb, MAX(bb, 21600))), 
         LAMBDA(x, y, MAX(x-y, 0)))))/60/60))))



86400 = 1 day = 24×60×60 = hours × minutes × seconds
57600 = 16:00 = end of date
21600 = 06:00 = start of date
36000 = 10 hours = 16:00-06:00 = 57600-21600 = duration


the whole journey to get this formula with full logic and step-by-step tutorial can be seen in included spreadsheet demo


for EVENING:
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(LET(b, B2:B20, c, C2:C20, 
 bb, b*86400, cc, c*86400, cd, cc+((c<b)*86400), 
 IF((bb>72000)*(cd>cc)*(cc>57600), 
   MAP(cc, LAMBDA(cc, MIN(cc-57600, 14400))), 
   MAP(BYROW(cd, LAMBDA(cd, MIN(cd, 72000))), 
       BYROW(bb, LAMBDA(bb, MAX(bb, 57600))), 
         LAMBDA(x, y, MAX(x-y, 0)))))/60/60))))


etc.
side note: DST (daylight saving time) is not accounted for
